# Proof: The coordinates of the witch of Agnesi curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry, trigonometry

I need to prove that the coordinates ofthe  witch of Agnesi curve is: $$x=2a\cot \theta$$ and $$y=2a\sin ^2 \theta$$
Any idea how to prove it?
And I don't understand how we got $a$...
(because the radius of the circle is 1).

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: How *do you* define the witch of Agnesi curve? Anyway, here you have a nice way of seeing it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WitchofAgnesi.html

Comment: @DonAntonio, I add a picture, and I didn't understand whats written at the link...

Comment: I know the geometrical picture, @Yoav. Anyway, $\;a\;$ is the circle's radius so if in your case it is a unit circle then $\;a=1\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio, can you help me prove it?

Comment: @DonAntonio, how $a$ come to the coordinates?

Comment: Hold on some minutes, @Yoav.

Comment: OK! Thank you @DonAntonio!

Comment: Check now, @Yoav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll need some basic geometry/trigonometry. According to your diagram (with the radius being $\;a\;$ and thus instead of $\;y=2\;$ we have the horizontal line $\;y=2a\;$):

$$\begin{align*}(1)\;\;x=P_x&=AC=A_x\;,\;\;C=(0,2a)\\{}\\
\text{since} \;\Delta OEB\sim\Delta BPA\;,\;\sin t=\frac{AP}{AB}\implies (2)\;\;y= P_y&=2a-AP=2a-AB\sin t\\{}\\\text{By similarity or directly by Thales:}\;\;(3)\;\;AB\cdot AO&=AC^2 \end{align*}$$

And now we can deduce stuff:

$$2a\cot t=2a\frac{A_x}{A_y}=2a\frac{A_x}{2a}=A_x=x$$

and now from (3) we get

$$AB=\frac{x^2}{AO}=\frac{x^2}{\frac x{\cos t}}= x\cos t=2a\cot t\cos t=2a\frac{\cos^2t}{\sin t}$$

and finally from (2) we get

$$y=2a-AB\sin t=2a\left(1-\cos^2t\right)\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you! if Something will be unclear I'll ask...

Comment: What is $C$? I don't see the point at the picture...

Comment: I wrote it there, in the rightmost extreme of (1), @YoavFridman

Comment: But point $P$ can move, why $P_x$ is $AC$??

Comment: When point $\;P\;$ moves so does point $\;A\;$, @Yoav...this is *your* diagram!

Comment: Yes, you right! $A$ moves if $P$ moves... (I forget this...)

Comment: Why $AB\cdot AO=AC^2 $??

Comment: @YoavFridman Geometry: From an exterior point to circle: the product of the secant from that point ($\;AO\;$) by its exterior segment ($\;AB\;$) equals the squared tangent to the circle from that point ($\;AC^2\;$ )

Comment: @DonAntonio Does your last statement have a name?